# Error: spawn cmd ENOENT at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

C:\repo\dem1>npm start

> @ start C:\repo\dem1
>   expo start

Starting project at C:\repo\dem1

Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)

```
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)

at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Answer (score 2):

checked system variables one more time and found the cause of the problem: missing C:\Windows\System32\ variable. I added it and that solved my problem

Hope, it help you too.

Comment: Hi Daiene! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Glad this worked. Could you edit your answer to add in the specific steps you took to help future visitors? What variables were missing?